# Capybara: undefined method `assert_text' for #<Capybara::Session>, undefined local variable 'response'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

Integration test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Create categories and items" do

    before do
        ItemCategory.create(id: 1, name: "Camping, backpacking, hiking gear")
        ItemName.create(itemcategory_id: 1, name: "2-person tent")
        ItemName.create(itemcategory_id: 1, name: "Sleeping bag")
        ItemCategory.create(id: 2, name: "Household tools")
        ItemName.create(itemcategory_id: 2, name: "Electric drill")
    end

    it "should have the categories and items" do
        ItemCategory.count == 2
        ItemName.count == 3
    end

    describe "Request page flows" do

        before do
            visit '/'
            select "Camping, backpacking, hiking gear", from: "ItemCategory"
            click_button "Go!"
            save_and_open_page
        end

        it "should go to the right request form" do
            expect(response).to have_content("Camping, backpacking, hiking gear")
            page.assert_text("Camping, backpacking, hiking gear")
            ItemName.where(itemcategory_id: ic.id).all.each do |i|
              page.has_text?(i.name)
            end
            ItemName.where.not(itemcategory_id: ic.id).all.each do |i|
              page.has_text?(i.name)
            end
        end
    end
 end
```

At the second it block (`it "should go to the right request form"`) it appears the Capybara response isn't happening... or whatever semantics I should use, here are the errors:

```
expect(response).to have_content("Camping, backpacking, hiking gear")
==> undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fef26c24260>

page.assert_text("Camping, backpacking, hiking gear")
==> undefined method `assert_text' for #<Capybara::Session>
```

The second seems to make it painfully obvious that Capybara still thinks I'm in a user session, where I'm just filling in input/ clicking buttons. But... why? I already clicked `click_button`, and adding the `save_and_open_page` does show the correct output.

Comment: `expect(page).to have_content("Camping...")` is what you're looking for.

Comment: That gives me this: `Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html"`, which I don't understand because I'm not looking for an `xpath`??

Comment: Do you have multiple `<html>` tags in your page?

Comment: Just the close and end...